# Inserting watermark inside an Ext JS panel

Tags: extjs, styles, extjs4, panel, watermark

How can I insert (and align) a watermark (image) inside a panel. I'm using Ext JS 4.1.1

Answer (score 3):

You can use css for that. Add a `cls` property into your panel:

```
cls: 'watermark'
```

And then define it in your css file something like this:

```
.watermark {
   background-image: url('your file');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: right bottom;
}
```

Comment: This sounds correct, but it doesn't work. No error but the image didn't show up.

Comment: Well, you need to debug it. Check all HTML elements in debug window (Chrome, FF has this feature). See what CSS elements are applied to the background, check/uncheck some of them to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Try using bodyCls instead. The cls config will add the class to the outer-most DOM element, but bodyCls applies it to the visible body of the panel.